# Jagged images in IE7

Tags: html, image, internet-explorer-7

I'm fighting with IE7, trying to "make this happen". The thing is that I dont want to use JavaScript. I want to find a solution in case JavaScript is not on. As you can see the image is jagged, pixelated. But if I change the image format, to JPG for instance, it looks much better. I need to have them with transparent background. Any idea why is this happening?

[image: Example].

```
<div id="container">

<!-- <div id="main" role="main">-->

    <h2>Example</h2>

    <div id="group_1" class="level_1">
        <img src="img/woodMain.jpg"alt=""> 

        <ul id="ul_1" class="level_2">

            <li class="level_2">
              <label class="level_3"><img src="img/newLabel.png"  alt=""></label>
              <img src="img/book_3.png">                 
            </li>

            <li class="level_2">
              <label class="level_3"><img src="img/newLabel.png" alt=""></label>
              <img src="img/book_4.png">                 
            </li>



        </ul>
    </div><!-- ends 1_group -->  

    <div id="2_group" class="ground_cero">

       <img src="img/2_group.png"alt="">

       <!--
        <ul>
            <li>
              <label><img src="" alt=""></label>


            </li>

        -->
    </div><!-- ends 2_group -->  

<!-- </div> --><!-- ends main -->

 </div> <!--! end of #container -->
```

and css:

```
body{ max-width: 100%; }

img{ 
/*max-width: 100%;*/
max-width: 100%;
height: auto; 
}


label{
max-width: 30%;
height: auto;
position: absolute;

}

label img{

}

div#container{

margin: auto;
border: 2px solid red;

}
/*
div#container div#main{
*/
/*border: 1px solid black;*/
/*max-width: 70%;
/*z-index: 1;
}*/


div#container div{

margin: auto;
max-width: 82%;
position: relative;
/*border: 1px solid red;*/

}

div#container div img{
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
div#container  div#group_1 #ul_1{

padding: 0px;   
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0px;
/*border: 1px solid green;*/
bottom: 3%;
left: 0px;
max-width: 100%; 
position: absolute;
margin-left: 2%;



}

div#container div #ul_1 li {
list-style: none;
margin-left: 5%;
display: inline-block; /* others than IE 7 */
position: relative;
zoom: 1; /* calling the haslayut method inside IE7 */
*display: inline; /*targeting IE6-7 */
bottom: 0px;
width: 25%;
vertical-align: bottom;


}
```

Comment: Are you stretching the image? That will surely pixelate it.

Comment: @Juan well YES! cuz the whole design is fluid. In IE-8 everything looks good; for instance.

Comment: The algorithm for stretching images is just not as good in IE7.